# Get nth item of txt file in batch scripting

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I have a list with on each line a different item, let's just say for this example that they are fruits:

```
echo apples>c:\temp\fruits.txt
echo bananas>>c:\temp\fruits.txt
echo pears>>c:\temp\fruits.txt
echo strawberries>>c:\temp\fruits.txt
echo peaches>>c:\temp\fruits.txt
```

I'm asking the client to make a selection of these by entering the line number of the desired fruits. Next, I want to echo the fruits they have chosen. for one fruit, I got it working:

```
set /p var=which fruit?  %=%

set /a var-=1
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('more +%var% c:\temp\fruits.txt') DO (      
  echo you have chosen: %%a
  goto :leave
  )
:leave
```

However, I want the user to be able to select multiple fruits, for example 2,3 for bananas and pears. I don't seem to get this working. The best guess I've had is this:

```
for %%i in (%var%) do for /f "delims=" %%a in ('more +%%i c:\temp\fruits.txt') DO (
    echo you have chosen: %%a   
)
```

However, I have no idea where to put the goto statement to limit the results of the "more" statement , if that is even possible. How can I fix this, or is there an better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    (
        echo apples
        echo bananas
        echo pears
        echo strawberries
        echo peaches
        echo kiwis
        echo oranges
        echo cherries
    ) > fruits.txt

    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%f in ('findstr /n "^" fruits.txt') do echo %%f - %%g
    echo.
    set /p "select=select :"
    echo.

    set "filter="
    for %%s in (%select%) do set "filter=!filter!/c:"%%s:" "
    for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%f in (
        'findstr /n "^" fruits.txt ^| findstr /b /l %filter%'
    ) do echo %%g
```

Comment: aa .Yes.The better way for writing the fruits.

Comment: This works, thank you very much! One little question though, how does `%%f` become the line number and `%%g` the fruit? I would think that `%%f` gets the value of the whole line as newlines are the standard delimiter. Or does the `:` make both the `:` and the newline delimiters?

Comment: @user1261104, the for loop handle one line at a time. The delimiter in the for loop is `:`, the tokens are 1 and the rest of the line (1,*), so the for each line (number:fuit) the split is done, %%f gets the number and the rest of the line goes to %%g

Answer (score 1):

`GOTO` could  break your `for` command .Instead I've wrapped your code into additional plain `for` loop and you can enter the numbers you want separated by the standard delimiters.E.g. test with `2,3,5` ; `5=2=6` , `1;6;2` ; `5 6 2` or combinations.

```
@echo off

(
    echo apples
    echo bananas
    echo pears
    echo strawberries
    echo peaches
    echo kiwis
    echo oranges
    echo cherries
) > fruits.txt

set /p var=which fruit?  %=%
break>"%temp%\empty"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo|set /p"=you have chosen: "
for %%V in (%var%) do (
    set /a chooser=%%V 
    set /a ender=chooser-1
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('fc "%temp%\empty" "fruits.txt" /lb  !chooser! /t ^|more +4 ^| findstr /B /E /V "*****" ^|more +!ender!') DO (      
        echo|set /p"= %%a "
    )
)
endLocal
del /q /f "%temp%\empty"
```

this `fc "%temp%\empty" "fruits.txt" /lb  !N! /t |more +4 | findstr /B /E /V "*****"` will show the first `N` lines of a file (it compares it with an empty file and shows the differences) .Could skip a line that contains exactly `"*****"` but that is not a concern in this case. And with `|more +!N-1!` the rest of the lines are truncated.  So it will iterate through the numbers and will show each line there.

Comment: This also works, thank you very much! I guess this is what happens: with the `fc` to `/t` part you limit how many resuls you get back, where `!chooser!` is the number of results from the start of the list and endig with `*****` which the `fc` outputs. Then you search for `******`, saying it should output lines which don't have that string, starting with line `!chooser!-1` which is the fruit you're looking for. Is that about right?

Comment: just check the `fc` help. `/t` stands for text mode. `/lb`is ti show mismatches number , and `******` is the border between the two files in the output and is removed with `findstr` command.